# How to skip blank data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null

I wanted to skip blank data in MySQL.

My sample query is:

```
SELECT id, name, date from sample where name IS NOT NULL;
```

Sample table:

```
id     name         date
1                  24-04-2012
2      abc         23-04-2012
```

Now if I fire above query, it gives me both record but I want to skip data which is stored as blank i.e. There is nothing(**not even NULL**)?

So how can I skip 1st record? What should be my query?

**So how to skip blank data in MySQL?**

Please guide me.

Comment: Do you mean a blank string?  NULL literally means "nothing".

Comment: Yes..how can I skip 1st record from sample table?

Comment: use mellamokb's query below.  :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can eliminate both `NULL` and empty/blank strings from your results using the following:

```
 where name IS NOT NULL AND name <> ''
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1155a/6

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, `trim` is not even necessary.

Comment: `TRIM()` isn't necessary since string comparison with `<>` doesn't consider trailing spaces in MySQL.

Comment: @Marcus is correct, `TRIM()` is not needed in this case (in MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

This question is already solved by mellamokb, but here I propose a one way step based on ["How to check if a parameter is null or empty sql"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-sql) and [NULLIF mySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

```
where  nullif( trim(name) , '') is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, date from sample where trim(name)
```

Comment: Simply have column name as mentioned above. It will get validated since it's not a blank string -> ``

Comment: Then it is showing both records...I don't want record with blank data.