# Laravel whereNotNull statment not working properly

Tags: php, database, laravel

I fetching data from DB and when I do that, trying to eliminate null rows.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;

    $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
        ->whereNotNull('lat')
        ->whereNotNull('lng')
        ->where('lat', '!=', '')
        ->where('log', '!=', '')
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->where("building_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
        })
        ->orderBy('price')->paginate(8);

    return view("home", compact('estates', 'q'));
}
```

I can't figure out how to solve syntax error at this line:

```
   })
   ->orderBy('price')->paginate(8);
```

Comment: You'll have problems if you mix AND/OR wheres. Use a closure to group your where statements.

Comment: Could you give an example for this? @aynber

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: But when I delete other `->where` and `->orWhere` still getting all the lat and lng it doesnt matter null or not, for example like this; https://imgur.com/a/O8TmNS7

Comment: Are you sure the values are actually null and not empty strings?

Comment: you can see it yourself second row is empty https://imgur.com/a/uIqfa1t

Comment: That row looks more like an empty string than null, which does not evaluate the same.

Comment: Hmm, then any other idea to execute it?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10298620/9193055) should answer your question.

Comment: Add `->where('lat', '!=', '')->where('log', '!=', '')` to the query to check for non-empty strings.

Comment: Thank you. it's working could you give it as an answer? I'll check it @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for empty strings by adding `->where('lat', '!=', '')->where('log', '!=', '')` to your query. You'll also need to add a closure to break off your OR statements:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;

    $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
        ->whereNotNull('lat')
        ->whereNotNull('lng')
        ->where('lat', '!=', '')
        ->where('lng', '!=', '')
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where("building_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%");
        })

        ->orderBy('price')->paginate(8);

    return view("home", compact('estates', 'q'));

}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. it's working but, how can I solve the syntax error at this line `})

        ->orderBy('price')->paginate(8);`

Comment: Sorry, forgot a semi-colon. I also forgot to pass in the $q so the subqueries could use it.

Comment: @Barbie change `->where('log', '!=', '')` to `->where('lng', '!=', '')`

Comment: Spelling error, `log` should be `lng` in the second new `->where()` clause.