# How to Check Parameter is not null in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

I have a stored procedure. In this stored procedure I have to check that a particular parameter is not null. How can I do this? I wrote this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReelListings]
    @locationUrlIdentifier VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN   

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Sql varchar(max)=''

SET @Sql = 'SELECT CategoryName, CategoryUrlIdentifier,  LocationUrlIdentifier, Directory.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category.Name ORDER BY CASE WHEN '''+ @locationUrlIdentifier + ''' = Location.UrlIdentifier THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN ''' + @locationUrlIdentifier + ''' IS NULL AND Directory.LocationId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END END, Directory.SortOrder ) AS ''RowNo'', Category.Name AS CategoryName, Category.UrlIdentifier AS CategoryUrlIdentifier, dbo.Location.UrlIdentifier AS LocationUrlIdentifier, Directory.DirectoryId, CASE WHEN ''' + @locationUrlIdentifier + ''' = Location.UrlIdentifier THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN ''' + @locationUrlIdentifier + ''' IS NULL AND Directory.LocationId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END END AS CategoryOrder    FROM dbo.Directory  INNER JOIN dbo.Category ON Directory.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Location ON dbo.Directory.LocationId = location.Location_ID ) AS content INNER JOIN dbo.Directory ON content.DirectoryId = Directory.DirectoryId WHERE content.RowNo =1 '

if (@locationUrlIdentifier is null)
begin
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' and 1=1'
end
else
begin
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' and CategoryOrder = 1 '
end

print @SQl
EXECUTE (@Sql)
 END
```

This will work in SQL but this will return a null Dataset in Codebehind.

Comment: It will return nothing so in code behind Dataset is null

Comment: Better if you can give full script. Then easy to find the problem

Comment: I think you should use NULLIF Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you join strings and `NULL`s together, the result is `NULL`. By the time you're asking about whether the variable is `NULL`, you've already done this:

```
' + @locationUrlIdentifier + '
```

Several times. If it's `NULL`, so will `@Sql` be.

You might want to consider using [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace the `NULL` with a suitable replacement (e.g. an empty string):

```
' + COALESCE(@locationUrlIdentifier,'') + '
```

You also still have a logic error on your final construction. If the variable is `NULL`, you'll have a where clause saying:

```
WHERE content.RowNo =1 1=1
```

Which isn't valid. I don't think you should be appending anything.

---

I'm also not clear on why you're doing this as dynamic SQL. The below seems to be an equivalent query which can be executed directly:

```
SELECT
    CategoryName,
    CategoryUrlIdentifier,
    LocationUrlIdentifier,
    Directory.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Category.Name ORDER BY
                CASE
                    WHEN @locationUrlIdentifier  = Location.UrlIdentifier THEN 1
                    WHEN @locationUrlIdentifier IS NULL AND Directory.LocationId IS NULL THEN 0
                    ELSE 2
                END,
                Directory.SortOrder
        ) AS RowNo,
        Category.Name AS CategoryName,
        Category.UrlIdentifier AS CategoryUrlIdentifier,
        dbo.Location.UrlIdentifier AS LocationUrlIdentifier,
        Directory.DirectoryId,
        CASE
            WHEN @locationUrlIdentifier  = Location.UrlIdentifier THEN 1
            WHEN @locationUrlIdentifier IS NULL AND Directory.LocationId IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 2
        END AS CategoryOrder
    FROM
        dbo.Directory
            INNER JOIN
        dbo.Category
            ON
                Directory.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Location
            ON
                dbo.Directory.LocationId = location.Location_ID
    ) AS content
        INNER JOIN
    dbo.Directory
        ON
            content.DirectoryId = Directory.DirectoryId
WHERE
    content.RowNo =1 and
    (@locationUrlIdentifier or CategoryOrder = 1)
```

Comment: ya sorry i just forgot to write and 1=1

Comment: @ABVyas - there's no need to add `and 1=1` to an otherwise well formed `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just in ONE query:

```
Select Query ...where ... 
  and ((@locationUrlIdentifier is null) or (CategoryOrder = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULLIF instead of IS NULL

Refer : [Check if a parameter is null or empty in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/how-to-check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-sql)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) check and then change the null to empty string

```
IF (ISNULL(@locationUrlIdentifier,'') = '')
```

OR even before this check you can use `ISNULL()` to convert from `NULL` to empty string if it persists to be a problem