# SQL - Select multiple columns which are NOT NULL and NOT EMPTY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Table 'anbieter' looks like :

```
Firma      | Blumenerde | Dachsubstrate | Rinden  | Substrate
-------------------------------------------------------------
Name 1     |             |       x       |         |
Name 2     |      x      |               |    x    |
Name 3     |      x      |       x       |    x    |
Name 4     |             |       x       |         |
```

What I need to do is:

Output Names (First Column) and select all Columns header which are NOT NULL and not empty ('')

For Example

```
Name 1 / Dachsubstrate
Name 2 / Blumenerde / Rinde
....
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM anbieter WHERE Blumenerde IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(Blumenerde) <> ''
```

This works great with one column...
But I need to make it work with some more columns like:

```
SELECT * FROM anbieter WHERE (Dachsubstrate OR Blumenerde) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM( ????? ) <> '';
```

How to "TRIM()" them ?

Hope you understand my point...

Comment: Please show what your expected output would look like

Comment: I just need to output alle column header which are NOT NULL  <> ' ' depending on my WHERE() criteria

Comment: So you need to get a row where all columns are populated?

Comment: Sorry it was a bit confusing... updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a parameter is null or empty in a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thanks for your help - got it working!

Comment: @SebastianGroßmann If the answer you accepted is right, your example is wrong. Please correct the question to say what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you just need to chain the conditions with `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM anbieter 
WHERE TRIM(Blumenerde) <> ''
AND TRIM(Dachsubstrate) <> ''
AND ...
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, NOT NULL is a surplus condition

Comment: Well ... Got it! Replaced AND with OR

SELECT * FROM anbieter 
WHERE Blumenerde IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(Blumenerde) <> ''
OR Dachsubstrate IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(Dachsubstrate) <> ''

Comment: Well it should return the 3rd row, where `Firma = Name 3 `

Comment: @SebastianGroßmann Does this really do what you want? It's only returning the rows that have all the columns filled in. It won't return `Name 1: Dachsubstrate`

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` conditions are redundant, since the inequality tests already exclude NULL values. `TRIM(NULL)<>''` will never return TRUE.

Comment: @SebastianGroßmann Can you explain why you accepted this, since it doesn't produce output like your example?

Comment: @Barmar - i had problems building the query with multiple TRIM (didnt know how to) this pushed me in the right direction to make it work... So it was a part-answered. My main questions was "how to TRIM" for everything else i had a workaround.... but i will Check your answer tomorrow too, maybe it fits better to my criterias but its late in Germany right now. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Firma, 
        CONCAT_WS(' / ', 
            IF(TRIM(Blumenerde) != '', 'Blumenerde', NULL),
            IF(TRIM(Dachsubstrate) != '', 'Dachsubstrate', NULL),
            IF(TRIM(Rinden) != '', 'Rinden', NULL),
            IF(TRIM(Substrate) != '', 'Substrate', NULL)) AS cols
FROM anbieter
HAVING cols != ''
```

`CONCAT_WS` skips over arguments that are `NULL`.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035df7/2)

Comment: This matches the output the OP edited into their post, unlike my answer which provides a completely different result, i have no idea which answer is correct though

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you seek?

```
Select firma, concat(REPLACE(coalesce(Blumenerde,''),'x','Blumenerde'),REPLACE(coalesce(Dachsubstrate,''),'x','Dachsubstrate'),REPLACE(coalesce(Rinden,''),'x','Rinden'),REPLACE(coalesce(Substrate,''),'x','Substrate')
from anbieter
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if any of the fields have a value, so in other words if at least one field is not null (which is a bit different from querying for rows where all fields are not null). So you could use (based on your example):

```
SELECT * FROM anbieter 
WHERE 
NULLIF(Blumenerde, '') IS NOT NULL OR
NULLIF(Dachsubstrate, '') IS NOT NULL OR
NULLIF(Rinden, '') IS NOT NULL OR
NULLIF(Substrate, '') IS NOT NULL
```

Or you could use `COALESCE` to check that at least one value is not null:

```
SELECT * FROM anbieter 
WHERE 
COALESCE(
    NULLIF(Blumenerde, ''),
    NULLIF(Dachsubstrate, ''),
    NULLIF(Rinden, ''),
    NULLIF(Substrate, '')
) IS NOT NULL
```