# Stored Procedure Update

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I want to insert those values also which have version null and and for version null I don't have status.

I am getting all data from datatable to procedure table type and then how do I check that the incoming data has version null or not?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertFilterData]
     @sqlDataTable SqlTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@sqlDataTable.Version IS NOT NULL OR @sqlDataTable.Version != '')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FilterCombination (Version, HotFix, Resourcetype, Language)
            (SELECT 
                 t1.Product, t1.Version, t1.HotFix, t1.Resourcetype, 
                 t1.Language 
             FROM
                 @sqlDataTable t1, Product_Version_Mapping t2  
             WHERE
                 t1.Product = t2.Product 
                 AND t1.Version = t2.Version  
                 AND t2.Status = 'Correct')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FilterCombination (Product, Version, HotFix, Resourcetype, Language)   
            (SELECT 
                 t1.Product, t1.Version, t1.HotFix, t1.Resourcetype, t1.Language 
             FROM
                 @sqlDataTable t1, Product_Version_Mapping t2  
             WHERE
                 t1.Product = t2.Product);
    END
END
```

This query is not working. Please help

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want. Also please expand on "not working". This doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: You don't specify your problem, but this is suspicious: `@sqlDataTable.Version is NOT NULL or @sqlDataTable.Version != ''`. I think you need an `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: Also, the first insert lists **four** columns in your `INSERT INTO` table name, but you provide **FIVE** columns in your `SELECT` .....

Answer (score 0):

For checking null values, you can use NULLIF like so...

```
IF NULLIF(@PreviousStartDate, '') IS NULL
```

Please refer below link.

[Check if a parameter is null or empty in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855331/check-if-a-parameter-is-null-or-empty-in-a-stored-procedure)